# How to hold a pointer/reference to abstract base class but still be copyable in c++

Tags: c++, c++11

So let's say I have some ABC in C++:

```
struct IRun {
    virtual ~IRun() {}
    virtual void run() =0;
};
```

And I have another class that I want to be provided an instance of this interface to work with:

```
struct Other {
    IRun* runner_;
};
```

The issue is that I have to hold runner_ as a pointer to get virtual dispatch (references are out as they aren't assignable).  I'd like to be "modern" in my usage, so runner_ probably belongs in a smart pointer.

I'd like Other to be copyable and not share state, so shared_ptr and unique_ptr are out.  The only option I can see is writing my own that copies the underlying object via a clone() virtual function?  Is there anything in standard C++ (<= C++11) that's meant for this use case?

Comment: Note that if you are OK with `Other` not owning `runner_` then the raw pointer solution would be fine and everything would work as you want it to. No need for smart pointers in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is correct, there is nothing built-in in C++ to do this.

You will have to create a `clone()` virtual function that creates a copy, and implement it in each subclass of `IRun`.